# ASP.NET Core MVC update partial view after submitig a form

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, partial-views

This is in ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1.

What I have is a main Index page on witch I load all my partial views.

```
<button type="button" id="CreateButton" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top: 20px;">Nova osoba</button>
<button type="button" id="LoadDataButton" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-top: 20px;">Ucitati podatke</button>
<div id="CreateEditView">
</div>
<div id="TablePeopleView">
</div>
```

The way I load data into "TablePeopleView" is like this.

```
function AjaxCall(url) {
    $("#TablePeople").replaceWith(
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "POST",
            success: function (html) {
            $("#TablePeopleView").html(html);
            }
        }));
}

$(document).ready(function () {
   AjaxCall("@Url.Action("IndexAjax")");
});
```

This calls the IndexAjax method from the controller and creates this partial view inside "TablePeopleView"

```
@model List<Person>
<table style="margin-top: 20px;" class="table table-condensed" id="TablePeople">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Ime</th>
        <th>Prezime</th>
        <th>Grad</th>
        <th>Postanski broj</th>
        <th>Broj mobitela</th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.ID</td>
            <td>@item.FirstName</td>
            <td>@item.LastName</td>
            <td>@item.CityName</td>
            <td>@item.PostalCode</td>
            <td>@item.MobileNumber</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-toolbar EditButton" data-url="@Url.Action("Edit","Zadatak")/@item.ID">
                    Uredi osobu
                </button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger DeleteButton" data-url="@Url.Action("Delete","Zadatak")/@item.ID">
                    Obriši osobu
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

And it works fine, gets the data and shows it on table.

When I want to create a new person I click on the "CreateButton" and get a new partial view inside "CreateEditView". The partial view looks like this.

```
@model Person
<div class="modal fade" id="CreateOrEditModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">

            @if (Model == null)
            {
                <h4 class="modal-title">Nova osoba</h4>
            }
            else
            {
                <h4 class="modal-title">Uredi osobu</h4>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form asp-controller="Zadatak" id="CreateOrEditModalForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Ime osobe</label>
                    <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" id="FirstName" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Prezime osobe</label>
                    <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" id="LastName" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Naziv grada</label>
                    <input asp-for="CityName" class="form-control" id="CityName" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="CityName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Poštanski broj</label>
                    <input asp-for="PostalCode" class="form-control" id="PostalCode" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="PostalCode" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Mobilni broj</label>
                    <input asp-for="MobileNumber" class="form-control" id="MobileNumber" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="MobileNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Pospremi osobu" class="btn btn-default" id="SavePerson" />
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="ClosePerson" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Zatvori</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

The way I get the partial view to show up in "CreateEditView" is like this.

```
$('#CreateButton').click(function () {
    var url = "@Url.Action("Create","Zadatak")";
    $("#CreateEditView").load(url, function () {
        $("#CreateOrEditModal").modal("show");
    });
});
```

The way I save date from the form "CreateOrEditModalForm" is with this.

```
$("#CreateEditView").on("click", "#SavePerson", function (event) {

    $("#CreateOrEditModalForm").removeData('validator');
    $("#CreateOrEditModalForm").removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');

    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#CreateOrEditModalForm");

    $("#CreateOrEditModalForm").validate();
    if ($("#CreateOrEditModalForm").valid()) {
        $("#CreateOrEditModal").modal("hide");
    }
});
```

I had to do it like this because it is loaded through a partial view witch is not loaded on page load.

After the form is validated it calls the "Create" method from the controller witch looks like this.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Person model)
{

if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        this._dbContext.People.Add(model);
        this._dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return NoContent();
    }
    return NoContent();
}
```

Now this is where my problem comes I think. If the "ModelState.IsValid" is valid the new person will be saved to the DB and it will return NoContent. I put no content so the page does not refresh but if I put `return RedirectToAction(nameof(IndexAjax));` like I did in the begginig it just loads the partila view in a new page like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OUfI.png)

I do not want that to happen, I just want the table to be refreshed with the new person while staying on the page.

Comment: Not sure how is your backend whole code.I share a whole demo you could check if anywhere different with yours which may cause render the partial in a new page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax allows websites to load content onto the screen without refreshing the page.

Here is a working demo you could check:

Model:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
}
```

View(`Views/Zadatak/Index.cshtml`):

```
<button type="button" id="CreateButton" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top: 20px;">Nova osoba</button>
<button type="button" id="LoadDataButton" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-top: 20px;">Ucitati podatke</button>
<div id="CreateEditView">
</div>
<div id="TablePeopleView">
</div>
@section Scripts
{   //be sure add _ValidationScriptsPartial....
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    <script>
    function AjaxCall(url) {
        //the same as yours..
    }   
    $(document).ready(function () {
       AjaxCall("@Url.Action("IndexAjax")");
    });
    $('#CreateButton').click(function () {
        //the same as yours..
    });
    $("#CreateEditView").on("click", "#SavePerson", function (event) {    
        $("#CreateOrEditModalForm").removeData('validator');
        $("#CreateOrEditModalForm").removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#CreateOrEditModalForm"); 
        $("#CreateOrEditModalForm").validate();
        if ($("#CreateOrEditModalForm").valid()) {
            $("#CreateOrEditModal").modal("hide");

           //add the following code....

            $("#TablePeople").replaceWith(
                $.ajax({
                    url:"@Url.Action("Create", "Zadatak")",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: $("#CreateOrEditModalForm").serialize(),
                    success: function (html) {
                        $("#TablePeopleView").html(html);
                    }
                }));
        }
    });
    </script>
}
```

Be sure modify your `CreateEditView.cshtml`:

```
@model Person
<div class="modal fade" id="CreateOrEditModal" role="dialog">
    //...

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @*change type="submit" to type="button"*@
                        <input type="button" value="Pospremi osobu" class="btn btn-default" id="SavePerson" />
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="ClosePerson" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Zatvori</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public class ZadatakController : Controller
{
    private readonly YourContext _context;

    public ZadatakController(YourContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAjax()
    {
        //change here....
        return PartialView("_IndexTable", await _context.Person.ToListAsync());
    }
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return PartialView("CreateEditView");
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Person person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(person);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            //change here....
            return PartialView("_IndexTable", await _context.Person.ToListAsync());

        }
        return View(person);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this but this is already what I have. Your and mine code is almost the same. This still refreshes the page after a new person is made. What I want is to create a new person, refresh the table with the new person (basically refresh the partial view with the table) and not refresh the page. I asked around a bit and someone told me that I would need to use a clinet framework like Angular or something. The question is can it be done without that. Still thank you for your answer.

Comment: If you only want to refresh the partial instead of refreshing the page.You could use ajax.Check my updated answer.

Comment: It does not work.
Here is the link: https://imgur.com/a/7k8tBJ8
It just tells me that it can not find the page when I put the HTML id as partial view.

Comment: Hi @FilipLukinić,Be sure put your partial view in Views/Shared folder or share your project structure.

Comment: Hey. I think I have it in the same folder. I put it a git repository, so if you can, you can check it out.

Link: https://cutt.ly/5jDdD4C.

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Hi @FilipLukinić,You do not have `TablePeopleView` partial view in your project.You need change the `TablePeopleView`  to `_IndexTable`.Check my updated controller.

Comment: Thank you so very much. It all works now.
Thank you so much again this has been bothering me for a month now.